# What is the oscillator used for on HT12E/D?

Tags: oscillator

Every tutorial I've found on the internet connects the oscillator in and the oscillator out with a resistor. What can these ports be used for?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! If you have a question about a specific part, you need to provide a link to a datasheet or other information so that people who want to answer have some clue what you're talking about. Remember, you're asking them for a favor, so make it easy for them!

Comment: They just set the frequency of the internal oscillator that's used to modulate / decode the signal. Your question is unclear as to whether you don't know why an oscillator is required or if the pins can be used for something else.

Comment: @PeterJ Thank you for a good answer. I'm completely new to electronics..

Comment: @FriendofKim, for your question below about transmitting wirelessly you probably want to check out things like this and you should be able to Google how to use them: https://www.sparkfun.com/search/results?term=315mhz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an internal RC oscillator (the capacitor is inside, and connected to OSC1). The external resistor forms part of the oscillator.

see the datasheet: http://www.holtek.com/pdf/consumer/2_12ev120.pdf Page 9 gives the oscillator frequency vs. the resistor value.

[image]

Comment: I'm completely new to electronics. I'm currently reading _Practical Electronics for Inventors Third Edition_ because I want to make some circuits in my spare time. So thank you for your reply!

Comment: Can this oscillated signal be amplified and connected to an antenna? Is it AM in that case?

Comment: No, that isn't something it would make sense to do.

Comment: Do you choose the resistance to set the output frequency on the DOUT port?

Comment: The oscillator frequency sets the timing, as shown in the datasheet. Four clock cycles per bit.